# Securing apache CXF REST and SOAP services and retrieving authorities in code

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf, ws-security

I have followed the article here http://chrisdail.com/2008/08/13/http-basic-authentication-with-apache-cxf-revisited/

I now have a working interceptor for my soap service that wont let the services be used without the username and password.

I have a couple of questions though:

1. How can I, in a different package in my business logic, access the authorisation object to find out who is logged in and their roles?
2. How can I attached the same system to a rest service, is it possible or do I need to do it separatley?

Cheeers,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within the service, you can do something like:

```
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().get(AuthorizationPolicy.class);
```

to get the AuthorizationPolicy and use that for whatever actions you need.

Comment: spot on worked perfectly first time thanks.  Any ideas about adding the same secutiry to a jax-rs setup?